# Windows Script to pick data from word file to intranet site

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

I have a Word file with two columns viz .

> Product and Description.

```
Ex.
Product    Description
Item1     Mango is a great fruit
Item2     Dinosaurs are still around. Maybe you havn't looked around that well.
Item3     IT is not for all
```

..

I have a Intranet URL where

```
Item1, Item2, Item3..
```

are all listed and there is checkbox beside each Item. What I do now is copy the description from Word file and Paste it to place holder of description on Intranet URL.

As of now, I do this all manually. 
Here is the process : I copy the `Item1` text (say `Mango is a great fruit`) and open Intranet URL and click on `Item1` and paste the description (say `Mango is a great fruit`). Then do it over and over again for all Items.

Is there a automatic way of doing it in Powershell ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A `Macro keyboard\mouse recording program` will help you.  You record a series of keystrokes and clicks into a macro, and then you can play them back with a single keypress, to fill in all the fields.

Comment: How can i do it ? if u can pls suggest. As I see it, I should download any third party software which records the keyboard and then go from there.

Comment: I can't recommend any particular program - I haven't had the need to use one for many years.  See if you can find a trial or freeware one and give it a run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing would be to take the text and put it in a regular text file. Then you can import each line as an array.

```
$a = Get-Content "items.txt"
```

This will take each line as a string in an array. Next you would probably trim the string to fit your needs.

```
$a = $a.Substring(4)
```

Or whatever number of characters you want to remove. Without knowing what your intranet site looks like, I can't be too specific on what you should do next. [Here](http://www.pvle.be/2009/06/web-ui-automationtest-using-powershell/) is an article with functions for filling out webforms. So your code would basically be

```
ForEach($b in $a){
SetElementValueByName $elementname $b $position
}
```

I hope this gets you going!